# What's wrong with a request to Dropbox?

Tags: delphi, dropbox, indy

I have valid access token to Dropbox account (API v2), Delphi 7 and, Indy 10.
When I try to use this token I have exception 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request'.
I look at [Dropbox API v2](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder) and can't understand:
what's wrong with the request?

```
procedure TDropboxSaveFilterForm.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  AccessToken = 'Hq7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source: TStringList;
  Res, URL: WideString;
begin
  Source := TStringList.Create;
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
  URL := 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder' + '?' +
         'Authorization=Bearer ' + AccessToken;
  Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source);
  Source.Free;
end;
```

New code with the header, error the same :-(.
According to [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=index.html): Request  Specifies the header values to send to the HTTP server.

```
procedure TDropboxSaveFilterForm.TestHeaderButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  AccessToken = 'Hq7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  URL = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source: TStringList;
  Head, Res: WideString;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Source := TStringList.Create;
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
  Head := 'Authorization: Bearer ' + AccessToken;
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.Write(Head, Length(Head));
  Stream.Position := 0;
  IdHTTP.Request.Source := Stream;
  Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source);
  Source.Free;
end;
```

Comment: The authorization is not part of the requested URL, but should be send in the HTTP Headers.

Comment: Thank you, Roald van Doorn. I am tried using head, like this:
`code`
  Head := 'Authorization: Bearer ' + AccessToken;
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Stream.Write(Head, Length(Head));
  Stream.Position := 0;
  IdHTTP.Request.Source := Stream;
  Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source);
`code`
and have no success. Maybe you have an working example?

Comment: Thank you, @Roald.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Delphi/Indy, but perhaps if you share your latest code and the resulting error others would be more able to help. Also, check the response body itself for a specific error.

Comment: Thank you, @Greg
The resulting error the same :-(. I will add the code to the post.

Comment: Can you share the response body as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to put the authorization data in the request **URL** and in the request **body**. You should put it in the request **headers** instead. Use the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property to send a custom `Authorization` header value, eg:

```
procedure TDropboxSaveFilterForm.TestHeaderButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  AccessToken = 'Hq7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  URL = 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source: TStringStream;
  Res: String;
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Source := TStringStream.Create('JsonParamsHere');
  try
    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    try
      IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
      IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + AccessToken;
      IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source);
    finally
      IdHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Remy.
I don't need any parameters - all by default.
I tried this and tried `IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer ' + AccessToken);` and 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' in the both cases.

Comment: @OlegAdibekov read the Dropbox documentation more carefully. The `/list_folder` resource takes five JSON parameters as input, two of which (`path` and `recursive`) ARE NOT optional.

Comment: You are right, @RemyLebeau. It works OK with this addition: `Source.WriteString('{ "path": "" }');`. Thanks.

Comment: @OlegAdibekov I would use `Source := TStringStream.Create('{"path":""}');` instead, as my answer suggests.